# How to evaluate the integral $\int \sqrt{1+\sin(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

**To find:**

$$\int \sqrt{1+\sin(x)} dx$$

**What I  tried:**

I put $\tan(\frac{x}{2}) = t$, using which I got it to:

$$I = 2\int \dfrac{1+t}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt$$

Now I am badly stuck. There seems no way to approach this one. Please give a hint. Also, can we initially to some manipulations on the original integral to make it easy? Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$$(1+\sin x)=\left(\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2$$

$$\implies\sqrt{1+\sin x}=\left|\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right|$$

Comment: I have the strange feeling that what I did is wrong somewhere. May I ask your opinion about what I did ?

Answer (score 11):

In the first quadrant,

$$\sqrt{1+\sin x}=\sqrt\frac{1-\sin^2x}{1-\sin x}=\pm\frac{\sin'x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}$$ which you can integrate mentally, giving $\mp2\sqrt{1-\sin x}$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an absolute value in the numerator, $\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos x|$.

Comment: @mickep: probably. By laziness, I leave a $\pm$.

Comment: If you want to avoid the $\pm$, then you could write the primitive as $-2\cos x/\sqrt{1+\sin x}$.

Comment: @mickep: nope, I want to make the implicit change of variable and antiderivative obvious ($\sin'$ was on purpose). In this answer, I consider the sign discussion as routine work, this is not my point.

Comment: @mickep: I have rephrased to avoid any distraction with the sign issue.

Comment: So simple .... after seing your nice solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yep, a similar trick works well to integrate the secant/cosecant. Cheers.

Comment: Can we say then that the result is $$\int \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \frac{|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\pm \int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx$$ Or should we wite the last one as $\text{sgn}(\cos(x))\cdot \int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx$ ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @MaryStar: the square root being non-negative, the antiderivative must be a non-decreasing function. The expression over the whole real line is a little more complicated.

Comment: So, is the formulation I wrote wrong? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @MaryStar The one with the $\text{sgn}$ in front is probably wrong.

Comment: The other one with $\pm$ ? @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 5):

May be another way, trying to get rid of the radical.

Let $$\sqrt{1+\sin x}=t^2\implies x=-\sin ^{-1}\left(1-t^4\right)\implies dx=\frac{4 t^3}{\sqrt{1-\left(1-t^4\right)^2}}\,dt$$ So, $$I=\int \sqrt{1+\sin x}\,dx=\int\frac{4 t^3}{\sqrt{2-t^4}}\,dt$$ Now, let $$t^2=v\implies t=\sqrt v\implies dt=\frac{dv}{2 \sqrt{v}}$$ $$I=\int\frac{2 v}{\sqrt{2-v^2}}\,dv=-2 \sqrt{2-v^2}+C$$

Comment: There is no real benefit in the first change of variable with $t^2$ that you later redefine to be $v$. Go straight to $v$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. For sure ! Shame on me ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, $$\sqrt{1-(1-t^4)^2}=|t^2|\sqrt{2-t^4}$$

Answer (score 5):

\since, $$1=\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ 
$$\sin (x)=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
Therefore, we can put the above values of $1$ and $\sin (x)$ in the question. 
Now, we have. $$\int \sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+ \cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)            \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}    \,dx$$ 
And,$$\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2$$
By putting the above value, we get
$$\int\sqrt{\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+ \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2}\, dx$$
$$=\int \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,\,dx$$
$$=-2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in the substitution.
$$I = 2\int \dfrac{1+t}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt$$

$$I = 2\left(\int \dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}  }\,dt+ \int \dfrac{t}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}\,dt\right)$$

Define $$G:=\int  \dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}\,\,dt$$ $$AND$$ $$H:=\int \dfrac{t}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}\,\,dt$$

For G:

Since $t = \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right), dt = \frac{1}{2} \sec^2 \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) d \theta$

So $$G = \int  \dfrac{1}{\left(\sec^2 \left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)^{3/2}} \,\,\, \frac{1}{2} \sec^2 \left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) \,\,\,d \theta  \\\\ =  \frac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{1}{\sec \left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)} d \theta =  \frac{1}{2} \int  \cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) d \theta \\\\ = \sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) $$

For H:

$u := (1+t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies u^2 = 1+t^2 \implies 2u \,\,du = 2t\,\, dt $

$$H = \int \dfrac{u}{u^3}du = \int \dfrac{1}{u^2}du = -u^{-1} = -(1+t^2)^{-1/2} = -\left(\sec\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)^{-1} = - \cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) $$

Incorporating G and H with $I = 2(G+H)$, then the answer is done (Be careful about the sign of I).

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sin(x)$ as $\cos(\frac\pi2-x)$.
Use formula $\sqrt{1+\cos(\frac\pi2-x)} = \sqrt2\cos(\frac\pi4-\frac x2)$
Now integrate.
Answer is   $-2\sqrt2\sin(\frac\pi4-\frac x2) + C$

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference