# Length of cardiod $r=1+\sin\left(\theta\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I'm pretty sure this is correct since I'm able to justify each of the steps but I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way that isn't just skipping steps? Because I had to do 2 substitutions, one of which converted sine into cosine.

\begin{align*}
\text{Length }= & \ 2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{2 + 2\sin\left(\theta\right)} d\theta \\
= & \ 2  \sqrt{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1 + \sin\left(\theta\right)} d\theta\\
= & \ - 2\sqrt{2} \int_{\pi}^{0} \sqrt{1+ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) } dx \\
= & \ - 2\sqrt{2} \int_{\pi}^{0} \sqrt{1+ \cos\left(x\right) } dx \\
= & \ - 2\sqrt{2} \int_{\pi}^{0} \sqrt{2 \cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} dx \\
= & \ - 4 \int_{\pi}^{0} \left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right| dx \\
= & \ 4 \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) dx \\
= & \ 4 \cdot 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\left(u\right) du \\
= & \ 8 \left[\sin\left(u\right)\right]_{u=0}^{u=\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
= & \ 8 \left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(0\right) \right] \\
= & \ 8 \\
\end{align*}

edit: admittedly, I do know of other answers but I have no idea how one would have come across such trigonometric identities, or reason out how such an identity would be beneficial.

Comment: In response to your edit: after you practice, get some feedback by checking your answers against the textbook or using this site, and repeat. You want the $1 + \sin x$ to be a perfect square to get rid of the pesky square root. You already know how to do this with $1 + \cos x = 2 \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}$ so you are not as bad at this as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

\begin{align*}
\text{L }= & \ 2 \sqrt2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1 +\sin\theta}\> d\theta 
= \ 2  \sqrt{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\left(\sin\frac{\theta}2+ \cos\frac{\theta}2 \right)^2} \>d\theta\\
= &\ 2\sqrt{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\sin\frac{\theta}2+ \cos\frac{\theta}2 \right) d\theta  = 8 \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct including the setup of the integral (using symmetry), but note that $1 + \sin x = (\cos x/2 + \sin x/2)^2$ as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901857/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-sqrt1-sinx-dx).

When taking the square root you have $|\cos x/2 + \sin x/2|$, but since this equals $|\sqrt{2} \cos(x/2 - \pi/4)|$ which is non-negative for $-\frac{\pi}{2} ≤ x ≤ \frac{3 \pi}{2}$, $|\cos x/2 + \sin x/2| = \cos x/2 + \sin x/2$ for your integral.